# sencha touch-2; Store values into HTML

Tags: sencha-touch-2, sencha-architect

I've a store and model to make AJAX Call and get the result.

Here is my View

```
Ext.define('kids.view.YouTube', {
  extend: 'Ext.Component',
  alias: 'widget.YouTubePlayer',
  xtype: 'YouTube',

  config: {
    url: 'http://www.youtube.com/embed/',
    videoId: 'qsvpvqvApKo',
    vWidth: 420,
    vHeight: '315',
    styleHtmlContent: true,
    aaa: '1',
},
initialize: function() {
    var prod = Ext.create('kids.store.vids');
    prod.load(function ( ){ 
    prod.each(function (record, id){
        tmp = tmp + record.get('vid_url');
 });

  });
 this.callParent(arguments);
    var out = Ext.String.format(
      [
        '<div align="center">',
        '<iframe width="{0}" height="{1}" src="{2}"',
        'frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe>',
        '</div>'
      ].join(''),
      this.getVWidth(),
      this.getVHeight(),
      **tmp //(the dynamic variable i formed in onLoad event of store**
    );
    console.log(tmp);

   this.setHtml(out);
}
 });
```

I used `prod=ext.create('kids.store.vids');`
and i'm using `onload` function, which is fetching values correctly.

how can i use tmp variable out side of onload, becuase the variable is becoming empty. and inside the store.load(function) i can not use `this.callParent()`

h**ow can i pass dynamic html here, as per the store returned values?**

help me

Pavan

Answer (score 0):

Got it thanks
i've used panel.setHtml to update the html from the variable which i got from store.

thanks